# How to update Galaxy Nexus from 4.0.2 to 4.2?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I had a Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.2.1 and it broke. My insurance replaced it, so I have a new Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.0.2. The new phone doesn't show that any system updates are available. (Well, I think it updated from 4.0.0 to 4.0.2 as soon as I turned it on, but nothing since then.) How do I update it to 4.2?

(Sorry if I'm not giving enough information; I'm new and I'm not sure what's relevant.)

QUESTION RESPONSES:
-I am in Canada and my provider is Mobilicity.
-I have tried going to About Phone -> System Updates and nothing shows up.  When I first got the phone, it updated from like 4.0.0 or 4.0.1 to 4.0.2, but that's all that has showed up.  I also tried clearing the cache and force stopping Google Services Framework, as suggested in another thread.
-I don't really know what it means to install the update manually; I guess I'm willing to, but I feel that something must be wrong because this is the exact same phone (as far as I can tell) I've had for the last year with the exact same provider.  When I got this phone one year ago, it ran Jelly Bean automatically, so I don't get why this one wouldn't do the same automatically.

NEW INFO:
-Sometimes when I click System Updates, after it says there no updates available and shows "Last checked for updates" as the current time, it starts downloading a 41.2 MB "Android System Update".  After it downloads, it restarts and gets that picture of the robot having surgery, but it's still running 4.0.2.

---

I don't think this question is a duplicate of the one posted, because this is a case where I *know* there is an official update from the carrier/manufacturer, but my phone isn't seeing it.

I noticed another thing: when it downloads the "Android System Update" and restarts, the picture of the robot starts off as a green guy standing up with a blue thing spinning in his chest, but then it changes to the green guy laying down with a red caution triangle over his chest.  Does that tell me anything?

Comment: I checked the general thread you mentioned on how to update the OS and followed it to the thread "When will my device get the 4.2 update?" which says that the Samsung Galaxy Nexus for Canada Bell (not my carrier, but in my country) got the update in March 2013.  I remember getting the update from 4.1 to 4.2 on my old Samsung GN last spring as well.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to do the update manually.

Comment: I updated the question to show why I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: I agree. I don't think it's a duplicate, either.

Comment: I agree with you and Al, but since this has got a bit cluttered and you seem to have encountered a newer / more specific issue, I've close this in favor of the other one.  I hope that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

To update the system software, go to

```
Settings -> About phone -> Software update -> Check for updates
```

Comment: I updated my post to more clearly explain what I've been doing that hasn't worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If Settings > About phone > System updates turn out useless, my best bet, would be to look for in the XDA Developers forum.

Comment: Would that forum be to do a manual install?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Developers in the forum would provide custom unofficial builds for your phone. You'd need to "root" your phone (as is the local jargon), which would void your guarantee (i'm assuming its already void, since the device you're talking about is (relatively) old), so be sure to read and understand what you're doing :)

Comment: It's actually a brand new phone and I really don't want to void the warranty because I think it's flawed.